# How do you draw a JPanel on top of another?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I have 2 JPanels, StopWatchDial, which are basically just circles with their constructor being (topleftX, topleftY, diameter, and last parameter doesn't affect the dimensions). I'm trying to have it so there's a large outer circle drawn with a smaller inner circle drawn inside of it, but I'm having issues with that. I had assumed the process was suppose to be pretty simple with just overwriting the paintComponent method, but am I just overlooking something?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Stopwatch extends JPanel
{
    private StopWatchDial innerDial;
    private StopWatchDial outerDial;
    public Stopwatch(int x1, int y1, int width1, int x2, int y2, int width2)
    {
        innerDial = new StopWatchDial(x1, y1, width1, 60);
        outerDial = new StopWatchDial(x2, y2, width2, 1);
        this.add(outerDial);
        this.add(innerDial);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        outerDial.paintComponents(g);
        innerDial.paintComponents(g);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame starter = new JFrame("test");
        starter.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Stopwatch test = new Stopwatch( 150, 20, 300, 0, 0, 600);
        starter.add(test);
        starter.setSize(1000, 1000);
        starter.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm currently having is instead of being created on top of each other it produces this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/RGZbGtq.png]

Comment: show the code of `StopWatchDial`

Comment: You *might* fix your issue by calling super(); as the first line of paintComponent.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Ah I had tried super.paintComponent() as my first line earlier, but nothing changed. StopWatchDial's pretty long, but basically like I mentioned in the opener, it amounts to a circle being created with the first two variables being the x y coords of the top left corner and the third being the diameter. I did test it separately and it worked. The issue I'm currently having is instead of being created on top of each other it produces [this](https://i.imgur.com/RGZbGtq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I'm currently having is instead of being created on top of each other it produces this:

A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default. So your Stopwatch panel uses a FlowLayout. When you add two components to the panel they are displayed on a single line.

If you want the components on top of one another (using the Z axis) then you need to:

1. make the top panel non-opaque, by using innerDial.setOpaque(false).
2. Use a layout manager that displays component on the Z axis, like the `OverlayLayout`. I think you will need to set the alignmentX/Y values to 0.5f to make sure the components are centered on one another. Swing paints components in the reverse order they are added to a panel, so you would add the innerDial and then the outerDial to the stopwatch panel, so the outerDial gets painted before the innerDial.

The above answer is for information only. It should not be your final solution. Having 3 components is not the best design approach. You should only have a single `Stopwatch` component that is created so the programmer doesn't have to deal with layout issues every time they want to use the component.

> I had assumed the process was suppose to be pretty simple with just overwriting the paintComponent method,

The paintComponent() method is used for painting the Graphics of a component. It is NOT used to paint other components. You should not invoke paintComponents() on another component.

So instead of having 3 components, you can add all the painting code to the paintComponent(...) method of the `StopWatch` class. This would be a better design as all the logic related to displaying a stopwatch is in one class and is not dependent on the other classes being added to the stopwatch with a proper layout.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks for both the information how to do it and the better design for it! That makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

When StopWatchDial is a Component, one can stack them using a [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html).

```
public class Stopwatch extends JLayeredPane
{
    private StopWatchDial innerDial;
    private StopWatchDial outerDial;
    public Stopwatch(int x1, int y1, int width1, int x2, int y2, int width2)
    {
        innerDial = new StopWatchDial(x1, y1, width1, 60);
        outerDial = new StopWatchDial(x2, y2, width2, 1);
        add(outerDial, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        add(innerDial, Integer.valueOf(10));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final JFrame starter = new JFrame("test");
        starter.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Stopwatch test = new Stopwatch( 150, 20, 300, 0, 0, 600);
        starter.add(test);
        starter.setSize(1000, 1000);
        starter.pack(); // Could be used to do optimal layouting.
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> starter.setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> starter.setVisible(true)); does? I'm not sure I understand it. I tried using your code and then rewriting it looking in the JLayeredPane api, but I just get a blank frame.

Comment: (Or also `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`:) It makes the JFrame visible on the GUI events handling thread. It is an established and recommended (though often violated) technique, as some GUI parts require the event thread handling things sequentially. (Not really sensible.) / If you get a blank frame, I would use `pack()`  too. That probably will not help things; you probably need a working demo of [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) to see its functioning. My guess is some setPreferredSize or whatever.